# How can I compile a npapi plugin to mac

Tags: c++, macos, npapi

I have developed a NPAPI plugin for Google chrome.

I am searching for someone who can help me to compile the source code to Macintosh machine.
Or to give me simple instructions.

Comment: Check this [article ](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Writing_a_plugin_for_Mac_OS_X)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org), which provides an abstraction and tools for building a plugin for windows, mac, or linux and on windows will work in both NPAPI compatible browsers (firefox, chrome, safari, opera) and ActiveX (Internet Explorer).

Comment: It should be mentioned that you can also find code examples for a mac plugin in FireBreath, should you decide for whatever reason to still do a raw NPAPI plugin.  You need a plugin bundle (CFBundle) in XCode and the correct entrypoints.